# PHP array to string as parameters

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I want to convert array values into string. What should I use to join them as presented in goal?

Should I use `serialize()` or `implode()` or `http_build_query()` **or `array_walk()`** ?

```
$attributes = array(
    'autocomplete' => 'off',
    'class' => 'email',
    'id' => 'myform'
);

echo http_build_query($attributes, '', '" ');

// output
autocomplete=off" class=email" id=myform
```

**Goal:**

```
// output 
autocomplete="off" class="email" id="myform"
```

**Edit:**

I used `array_walk()` to gain goal

```
function myfunction($value, $key) {
    echo $key . '=" ' . $value . ' " ';
}

array_walk($atributes, "myfunction");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to combine these into a string for outputting on an HTML tag.

This reusable function should produce your desired result:

```
function get_attribute_string($attr_array) {
    $attributes_processed = array();
    foreach($attr_array as $key => $value) {
        $attributes_processed[] = $key . '="' . $value . '"';
    }

    return implode($attributes_processed, ' ');
}

$atributes = array(
    'autocomplete' => 'off',
    'class' => 'email',
    'id' => 'myform'
);

// this string will contain your goal output
$attributes_string = get_attribute_string($atributes);
```

P.S. `atributes` should have three Ts - `attributes` - mind this doesn't catch you out!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure that you'll get exactly the same array back, you have to use `serialize` (as it'll keep variable types) and `unserialize` to get your data back. Alternately, `json_decode` and `json_encode` work as well (but only maintains simple types as int/float/string/boolean/NULL). The data will be larger than `implode` and `http_build_query`, though.

Examples:

Consider the following array:

```
$array = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'bar' => false,
    'rab' => null,
    'oof' => 123.45
);
```

[`serialize`](http://www.php.net/serialize)/[`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/unserialize):

```
<?php
    var_dump( unserialize( serialize($array) ) );
    /*
        array(4) {
            ["foo"] => string(3) "bar"
            ["bar"] => bool(false)
            ["rab"] => NULL
            ["oof"] => float(123.45)
        }
    */
?>
```

[`implode`](http://www.php.net/implode)/[`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode):

```
<?php
    var_dump( explode('&', implode('&', $array) ) );
    /*
        array(4) {
            [0] => string(3) "bar"
            [1] => string(0) ""
            [2] => string(0) ""
            [3] => string(6) "123.45"
        }
    */
?>
```

[`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode)/[`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/json_decode):

```
<?php
    var_dump( json_decode( json_encode($array) , true) );
    /*
        array(4) {
            ["foo"] => string(3) "bar"
            ["bar"] => bool(false)
            ["rab"] => NULL
            ["oof"] => float(123.45)
        }
    */
?>
```

[`http_build_query`](http://www.php.net/http_build_query)/[`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/parse_str):

```
<?php
    parse_str( http_build_query($array) , $params);
    var_dump( $params );
    /*
        array(3) {
            ["foo"] => string(3) "bar"
            ["bar"] => string(1) "0"
            ["oof"] => string(6) "123.45"
        }
    */
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/RSmFRFgU)

Answer (score 1):

The **`http_build_query`** is the best option here since you have `key=>value` combinations

Answer (score 0):

Used `array_walk()` to gain goal

```
function myfunction($value, $key) {
    echo $key . '="' . $value . '" ';
}

array_walk($atributes, "myfunction");
```